# wrong in writing a random number in file php?

Tags: php

write variable `$rand`  in file applying this code:

```
echo $rand=rand(1,10);
$file = fopen($file_path,"w") or die('Cannot open file:  '. $file_path);

fwrite($file, $rand) or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file_path);
fclose($file );
```

the problem is the difference between the printed `$rand` value

and value that written in file?

ex: printed value is 5  but in file 9!!

Comment: You are printing `$rand` but writing `$random`.

Comment: `fwrite($file, $random)` <-- This is where the problem lies. Change it to `fwrite($file, $rand)`

Comment: Is it still broken after the edit?

Comment: sorry this is error in writing i mean $rand

Comment: yes still brokrn @MatthewJohnson

Comment: It should work as is.  Is there other code that is left out?

Comment: I have just tested your code and I get the same value printed on screen and in file

Answer (score 1):

Setting `$rand`

```
echo $rand = rand(1,10);
$file = fopen($file_path,"w") or die('Cannot open file:  '. $file_path);
```

Using `$random`

```
fwrite($file, $random) or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file_path);
fclose($file );
```

As you can see, those are too different variables.
Changing the line nr. 3 should do it

```
fwrite($file, $rand) or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file_path);
```

Comment: sorry this is error in writing i mean $rand